# iOS Swipe Gesture Recogniser for a quick-paced game

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, swift, swipe

I'm new to the iOS development world, so I'm starting off with a game that's neither Clash of Clans or the infamous 'I'm Rich'. I know Python and HTML/CSS so I will be able to cope with computer terms, but it would be great if you would be able to explain any answers.

A pattern flashes on the screen for half a second, let's say it is 'arrow left, arrow right, arrow left' (in picture form). Then the user has to replicate the pattern (in the right order) in order to boost forward. Basically, I'm asking what would be the simplest/most effective way of programming this? It would be great if I could easily add more patterns.

One way I thought that it could be done is to have an ID for each pattern, in which there are pre-defined 'nodes' that have to be swiped in a particular order. One benefit to this idea is that I can add patterns, however it could take a while to program them. Another idea I had is to assign an 'eraser' to the user's brush and it will detect when +-95% of the pattern is swiped. However, this would allow the user to swipe in any order.

Perhaps there is something super easy that I can do, but at the moment I have no idea. It would be great if I could do this in Apple Swift, however Objective-C is not a problem.

Thank you in advance,

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your own question in the title. Take a look at the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html). From there you'd just want to push gestures into an array and then compare to existing pattern arrays

Comment: Hey Quark, thank you for the response. It would be great if you could explain to me a bit more and how I could relate it to my app. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation? A gesture recognizer will call a specified method whenever the user makes that gesture. In this case, a UISwipeGestureRecognizer will listen for a swipe (up,down,left,right) and then call your specified method so you can do whatever work you need to do

Comment: Yeah I read it and your comment helps. So say I had the pattern 'left, right, left' appear on the screen, would I need to assign an ID to the picture? If so, how would it know that the user's input is equal to what the picture wants?

Comment: That's an exercise for you to figure out...but it comes down to associating an array of gestures/directions with a picture, and then comparing what the user swiped to that array